# On Redux update, how to prevent component from updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a small component that renders another page, the webpage URL has a token attached as an URL parameter, like in the sample bellow:

```
const SampleComponent =  () => {
  const { refreshToken } = useSelector(state => state.auth);
  const src = `${HOSTNAME}/page/?refresh_token=${refreshToken}`;

  return <webview src={src} />;
};

export default SampleComponent;
```

I have a special `cron` that runs every hour and updates the tokens and Redux is updated as well with the new tokens.

```
  window.tokensCron = new CronJob('0 0 * * *', () => {
    store.dispatch(getTokens());
  });
```

When the token is updated in Redux the page is being refreshed automatically.
How to prevent updating the component so that the refresh page won't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to use the token from redux state only when the component mounts?

You can make a custom hook that sets the token only once after the component mounts by deliberately leaving out a dependency of an effect, then use that in a HOC to pass the value of the token as it was when it mounted with other props to the component that needs the token:

```
//custom hook gets token only on mount
const useToken = () => {
  const token = useSelector(selectToken);
  const [val, setVal] = useState();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  useEffect(() => setVal(token), []);
  return val;
};
//hoc that will only re render if props change (not when token changes)
const withToken = (Component) => (props) => {
  const token = useToken();
  const propsWithToken = useMemo(
    () => ({ ...props, token }),
    [props, token]
  );
  return token ? <Component {...propsWithToken} /> : null;
};
```

Make sure that the component you pass to withToken is a pure component so it won't get re rendered when props passed to it won't change.

Code snippet with this example is below.

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const {
  useState,
  useRef,
  useEffect,
  memo,
  useMemo,
} = React;
const initialState = {
  token: 1,
};
//action types
const REFRESH_TOKEN = 'REFRESH_TOKEN';
//action creators
const refreshToken = () => ({
  type: REFRESH_TOKEN,
});
const reducer = (state = initialState, { type }) => {
  if (type === REFRESH_TOKEN) {
    return {
      ...state,
      token: state.token + 1,
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectToken = (state) => state.token;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (n) => (a) => n(a))
  )
);
//custom hook gets token only on mount
const useToken = () => {
  const token = useSelector(selectToken);
  const [val, setVal] = useState();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  useEffect(() => setVal(token), []);
  return val;
};
//hoc that will only re render if props change (not when token changes)
const withToken = (Component) => (props) => {
  const token = useToken();
  const propsWithToken = useMemo(
    () => ({ ...props, token }),
    [props, token]
  );
  return token ? <Component {...propsWithToken} /> : null;
};
const Component = ({ token }) => {
  const r = useRef(0);
  r.current++;
  return (
    <div>
      rendered: {r.current} token: {token}
    </div>
  );
};
//using React.memo to make Component a pure component
const PureWithToken = withToken(memo(Component));
const App = () => {
  const token = useSelector(selectToken);
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  //refresh token every second
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(
      () => dispatch(refreshToken()),
      1000
    );
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>token:{token}</div>
      <label>
        Toggle component with token
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={toggle}
          onChange={() => setToggle((t) => !t)}
        />
      </label>
      {/* when component re mounts it will have the newest token */}
      {toggle ? <PureWithToken /> : null}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state may be malformed.
As I see you have:

- a token that updates frequently
- an initial token, which is the first token value, and never change

So consider modify your state to follow this structure:

```js
state = {
  auth: {
    initialToken,
    refreshToken
  }
};
```

Then in your component, simply do that:

```js
const initialToken = useSelector(state => state.auth.initialToken);
```

**Important**, in your `useSelector` please returns only the value you want (your token, not the whole `auth`). Like that your component will update ONLY if your token changes.
As you do in your current code if `auth` changes, your component is updated even if token did not change.